# Which pattern of filling a form is most usual?

Tags: forms

Do users fill the left column of filelds first or do they use a Z pattern in filling the forms?

[image: Screnshot of form with two columns]

Comment: Can we assume the viewport accommodates the form width in full?

Comment: I fill forms according to [tab-order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabbing_navigation#Tab_order). ;)

Comment: Irrespective of reading order, I find the column break right between *address* and *city* to be most confusing. It's like inserting a column break between an image and its caption. Also: Your *address* is lacking a *d*.

Comment: This is likely to be substantially affected by the visual design of your form too (the vertical and horizontal spacing of form fields, the placement of labels relative to the inputs, etc.).

Comment: Does it matter?

Answer (score 45):

Rather than focussing on the Z or column pattern, you might want to consider  **grouping related information**. In your example it might be confusing for the user that *Address* and *City* are not grouped together.

So you could group the name fields, the address fields (*Address*, *City*, *Postal Code* and *Country*), the contact fields (*E-mail* and *Telephone*) and lastly the password fields (there should be a *Repeat Password* field).

The grouping idea comes from this [extensive usability guide to web forms](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/08/extensive-guide-web-form-usability/) where you'll find plenty of more ideas to optimise your forms.

Comment: Ooh I've just rated your answer up, this is the answer I would have given if I wasn't rushing, and it simply improves the form, which, as it stands, doesn't flow.

Answer (score 13):

Quite simply, try avoiding multi-column forms because [people may interpret the form's flow in various ways](http://baymard.com/blog/avoid-multi-column-forms).

[image]

Comment: Check out another thread I started:http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/39760/multi-column-form-design-is-there-a-consensus

Answer (score 0):

Each item on each line should relate to one and other.

For example "First Name" and "Second Name" Should be on the same line.

Having columned forms doesn't have a great user experience.